# How to create Object with nested Objects from an Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array `[1, 2, 3]` and I want to transfer it to object with nested **parent-child** **objects's series** like this :

```
{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null } }
```

If I have an array   `[1, 2, 3, 4]` the result will be like this :

```
{ value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: { value:4, rest:null } }
```

The best effort of me is this snippet of code :

```js
const arrayToList = (array) => {
  let list = { value: null, rest: null };
  for (let e of array) {
    array.indexOf(e) === 0 && (list.value = e);
    array.indexOf(e) >= 1 && (list.rest = { value: e });
  }
  return list;
};
console.log(arrayToList([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: did you see my answer ? if there's something went wrong with it please let me know

Comment: Yes. It works well.

Comment: Thank you my bro !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) like so:

```
let obj = arr.reduceRight((rest, value) => ({ value, rest }), null);
```

It starts building the object from the inside out; it starts by creating the innermost object and then it uses that object as the `rest` property for the next outer object and so on until there are no more items in the array.

**Demo:**

```js
let obj = [1, 2, 3, 4].reduceRight((rest, value) => ({ value, rest }), null);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I'd just say: Wonderful! because I hate writing functions with `if-else`.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin Thanks! The trick here is to start from the last item of the array and building the object from the inside out. Even if you use a simple `for` loop instead of `reduceRight`, if you start from the last item, you won't need `if-else`.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine-Aladdin ... like this https://jsfiddle.net/gd94npqf/ which is pretty much exactly what `reduceRight` is doing

Answer (score 1):

You can create such object by running below recursive function:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let transform = (arr, obj) => {
   if(arr.length === 0){
      return obj;
   } else {
      let last = arr[arr.length - 1];
      let newArr = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
      
      return transform(newArr, { value: last, rest: obj || null })
   }
};

console.log(transform(arr));
```

Comment: I want to avoid recursive functions for long-time execution if the array will be big.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function:

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];

function arrayToL(array) {
  let el = array.splice(0, 1)[0];
  let rtn = {
    value: el
  }

  rtn.rest = (array.length > 0) ? arrayToL(array) : null;

  return rtn;
}

console.log(arrayToL(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another solution using the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and reversing the array and start building object from the array end :

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 4, 5]

let obj = {} //object to be built

arr.slice().reverse().forEach(item => { //i used the slice method 
  //in order to avoid mutating
  //the original variable
  obj = { ...obj,
    ...{
      value: item,
      rest: obj
    }
  };

})

console.log(obj)
```